# Проверка корректности последовательности в массивах php

Tags: php, массивы, строки, arraylist

Есть два массива 1 - одномерный массив правильность последовательности элементов в котором нужно проверить и 2 - одномерный массив трафарет в котором указана корректная последовательность элементов. Было бы легко решить этот вопрос, если бы количество элементов равнялось друг другу, но в массиве 1 могут быть не все значения из массива 2, а только часть.

Для примера  можно взять массивы:

```
$ar = array(
   [0] => FIRST
   [1] => SECOND
   [2] => FIFTH
   [3] => SEVENTH
   [4] => EIGHTH
)

$pattern = array(
  [0] => FIRST
  [1] => SECOND
  [2] => THIRD
  [3] => FOURTH
  [4] => FIFTH
  [5] => SIXTH
  [6] => SEVENTH
  [7] => EIGHTH
  [8] => NINTH
  [9] => TENTH
)

$arFail = array(
   [0] => EIGHTH
   [1] => SEVENTH
   [2] => FOURTH
   [3] => SECOND
   [4] => FIRST
)
```

Как можно проверить, что последовательность значений в ar соответствует `$pattern`, а порядок значений `$arFail` не соответствует `$pattern`?

Comment: а) делаем функцию определения индекса эл-та в массиве, б) проходим массив, определяем индексы его эл-тов В ОБРАЗЦЕ, проверяем, что последующий больше предыдущего

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
function myCheck($arr, $pattern) {
  $lastPos = -1;
  foreach($arr as $value) { // перебираем массив
    $pos = array_search($value, $pattern); // ищем текущий элемент в pattern
    if ($pos !== false && $pos > $lastPos) { // если он найден, и позиция больше чем у предыдущего - все норм.
      $lastPos = $pos;
    } else return false; // если нет - не норм.
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: при нахождении элемента удаляйте начало `pattern` до найденной позиции.  Уменьшите число сравнений и не надо париться с `lastPost`.